# .idea folder disappears when zipping an Android Studio project in Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, zip

Working under Windows 7, we need to be able to zip up Android Studio projects and unzip them on a different machine. This is for a course I am teaching.

When we zip an Android Studio project folder, everything is included except the .idea folder which is missing. I have tried this both with Windows 7 Send To -> Compressed Folder and the 7-Zip tool. When I unzip the folder, the .idea sub-folder is missing. Even when I look in the .zip file, the .idea folder is missing.

The .idea folder "contain information core to the project itself" and so we cannot open the project up after it has been zipped and unzipped.

Does anyone know why zip would be excluding the .idea folder?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, they don't zip the file start with dot "."

Let say your android workspace is: C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\
and your folder that you need to zip is: "foo"
For 7-zip, right click foo folder, choose 7-zip --> Add to "foo.zip"
It will zip everything inside foo folder.

Comment: It looks like this is mostly true. What through me was the Windows will include the first folder that starts with a dot "." but then skip the rest. I have  reference to the "feature" - http://superuser.com/questions/566123/windows-7-send-to-compressed-zip-folder-omits-some-folders-whose-name-begins